# Use a variable in a shell command in a Scala program (not REPL)

Tags: scala

Inside a *program* - **not** the `REPL` - is it possible to introduce a string variable to represent the shell command to be executed ?

```
import sys.process._
val npath = opath.substring(0,opath.lastIndexOf("/"))
s"rm -rf $npath/*" !
s"mv $tmpName/* $npath/" !
```

The compiler says:

```
:103: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger
         s"mv $tmpName/* $npath/" !
     ^
```

Note that in the `REPL` this can be fixed by using

```
  :power
```

But .. we're not *in* the `REPL` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful workaround that *mostly* preserves the intended structure:

Use the

```
 Seq[String].!
```

syntax.  But by using spaces as a delimiter we can still write it out in a kind of `wysiwig` way

```
 import sys.process._
 val npath = opath.substring(0,opath.lastIndexOf("/"))
 s"rm -rf $npath/*".split(" ").toSeq.!
 s"mv $tmpName/* $npath/".split(" ").toSeq.!
```

The limitation here is that embedded spaces in the command would not work - they would require an *explicit* `Seq` of each portion of the command.

Here is a bit nicer if there were a set of commands to run:

```
Seq(s"rm -rf $npath/*",s"mv $tmpName/* $npath/").foreach{ cmd=>
   println(cmd)
   cmd.split(" ").toSeq.!
}
```